# Compiling pysvn (win64)

Tags: pysvn

I've tried to find the 64bit version for pysvn for a while now. The author say he cannot compile it for me because he have no 64bits system to test on.

So I downloaded the source from http://pysvn.barrys-emacs.org/source_kits/pysvn-1.7.0.tar.gz and the collabnet-subversion-1.6.1_src.zip sourcefile from Collabnet. I backported the python scripts so they would support python 2.5, opened Visual Studio and I just don't know where to start... It's just too many 3rd party libs and environment settings that is unknown to me.

Is there anyone that have compiled pysvn in Windows from scratch and could help me with this?

Comment: What happens if you run `easy_install pysvn`?

Comment: I have no time or wish to resolve this issue again, but as I recall from 2009, when asked the question, it was the svn dependencies that was difficult to build. 64bit is more common now and I assume svn is easier to build for 64bit today.

Comment: pysvn releases win64 builds as standard now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I ended up making a wrapper around the commandline version of svn ([sliksvn](http://www.sliksvn.com/en/home/)).

*the good:*

- svn.exe can return xml and also
  accepts files as input if you need to
  send text with linebreaks or special
  characters.
- Everything works on
  every 32bit and 64bit versions of
  python.

*the bad:*

- Error handling is not that fun, because svn.exe returns no other errorcode but 1.
- It's a bit slower than pysvn
- I haven't found a way for the user to interactively enter user and passoword, so I use TortoiseSvn for that.

Comment: Have you found any way to get direct access to the SVN API on x64 since 2009? I'm trying some combination of SlikSVN and Trac.

Comment: I am sorry, but I haven't looked into the problem. I think you'd be better of asking a new more specific question than mine.

Comment: I'm just going to do what you did, wrap the functionality I require. It's the easiest solution.